# Detect UUID change as fast as possible

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am using a raspberry pi as a beacon. When I change the UUID of the Beacon, I want my android app using [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) to detect the new UUID as fast as possible. In my knowledge two parameters can influence this: The scan period and the transmission rate. I am using 10Hz in the transmission and 300 ms in the setForegroundScanPeriod parameter. I am detecting the UUID change quite fast but I am wondering if there an optimal values for this two parameters to detect the change faster? Is there any other parameter that can influence this ?

Comment: Are you optimizing Android detection times in the background or foreground?  What OS version are you targeting?  The answer is different depending on answers to these questions.

Comment: I am interested only in the foreground detection and I am working with android 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Beacon Library's ranging APIs are is designed to give regular updates on which beacons are visible, by default every 1.1 seconds.  This means using default settings, and a beacon that advertises at 10 Hz (every 0.1 s), a first detection would come anywhere from 0.1-1.1 seconds later.

You can reduce the upper limit on this range by decreasing the scan interval in the library.  If you call `setForegroundScanPeriod(300l)`, the the maximum time to detection might go down to 300ms (0.3 seconds).  For this to work, you must ensure your beacon is advertising at least at 10 Hz, otherwise the shorter scan cycles will often miss a detection and actually lead to longer detection times.

You could reduce this number even more, but you generally want the scan cycle to be at least 1.1x the length of your transmission rate for infrequent transmissions, or 2x for frequent transmissions.  So for a beacon transmitting every 1s, set it to 1100ms. For one transmitting every 100ms, set it to 200ms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain me or post a link on why this 1.1x and the 2x relation between the transmission and the scan period,  I don't really get it ?

Comment: You do not want to have the scan period be exactly 1x the advertising period, because you miss seeing any packets being transmitted at the boundary of the scan cycle (when you stop and restart scanning).  If the ratio is exactly 1.0, you might miss all of them if they always come on the boundary.  The 2x recommendation comes when you have very fast scan cycles.  With fast cycles, you have more on/off transitions in scanning, so you have a much higher percentage of packets will be in transit on the boundary.  A 2.0 ratio makes it very likely at least one packet will be in each scan cycle.